# (event.target).text() returns url instead of text

Tags: jquery, events, text

Hopefully someone can give me some help.

I use the code below to add tags to an input field. However when adding a tag the entire path is included.

```
j('.ltags-add').click(function (event){
    contents = j('#link-tags').val();
    if ( contents != '' ) { sep = ', '; } else { sep = ''; }
    tag = j(event.target).text();
    j('#link-tags').val( contents + sep + tag );
});
```

`<span class="ltags-add">link 1</span>
<span class="ltags-add">link 2</span>`

When clicking a span it's supposed to return the text 'link 1', however it now returns 'http://www.example.com/create/link 1'

Does anyone have an idea why this happens and what I can do about it?

Cheers, G.

Answer (score 5):

I guess the `spans` are nested within an `anchor` ?

If so, don't use `event.target` (which not necessarilly represents your `.ltags-add` class), but `j(this).text()` which always references your `<span>` to which the click event was bound.

See this **Demo**: http://www.jsfiddle.net/YNUA5/1/